# Find common count by comparing 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3];  
arr2 = [2,3,4];
```

They have 2 common values. I want to compare them to get answer 2.
Is there any `lodash` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a lodash function named `intersection`.

**So, below is the code you can use to find the length of the common values of two arrays.**

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [2,3,4]

console.log(_.intersection(arr1, arr2).length);
```

Comment: It's all mine pleasure. Keep Asking!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [_.intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#intersection) and get common values

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [2,3,4];

console.log(_.intersection(arr1, arr2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Though it gets you common values of the two arrays, in this case 2,3 not just 2.

If what you want is the number of common values, just

```
_.size(_.intersection(arr1, arr2));
```

Or you could create your own function composing the other two:

```
let numberOfCommonValues = _.flowRight(_.size, _.intersection);
console.log(numberOfCommonValues([1,2,3,4,5], [1,4,5]));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly tell you if there's a lodash function to do this, but it seems kind of trivial.

Just go ahead and define a var, then iterate through one of the arrays and compare the value to every value in the other...

```
function countCommonalities(arr1, arr2) {
    var counter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for(var z = 0; z < arr2.length; z++) {
            if(arr1[i] === arr2[z]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```